# xCode 4.2 IDE layout

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, xcode4.2

I'm using xCode 4.2 on a MacOS X Snow Leopard, and I need some help dealing with the IDE.

Are there any settings for the following:

1. After I click on project navigator, I want it to be visible. Every time I build the project however, the panel is switched to the issues navigator. Is there a way to make the panel stay still?
2. When I press Shift+Win+C to show the debug area, I want it to be visible. Every time I do something (not sure what exactly causes that, it just happens), the debug area is hidden. Is there a way to make the panel stay still?
3. When I press "View->Utilities->Show utilities",  I want it to be visible. Every time I do something (not sure what exactly causes that, it just happens), the utilities panel is hidden. Is there a way to make the panel stay still?

P.S. Am I the only person experiencing those issues with xCode?